# Pootle, how to disable automatic translation suggestions

Tags: java, translation, pootle

I am using Pootle as localisation software for big project. My problem is, that every time we change something, some words are automatically translated to wrong texts.

Like we had texts: Ping, Chat, bet.... and those were new texts, and Pootle automatically translated it to all languages, of course completly wrong way. How can I disable this insane translations? I do not want any stupid software to translate, or even suggest wrong texts to well paid human translators.

We tried today to create new project, and we imported all language translations. In export files it is now ok, but when translator wants to translate, it shows him this wrong automatic translation text and in the comment box there is displayed -->  Translator comment: 75%.

Now problem is, that translator simply change 1 word and then clicks export. And wualaa.... all texts are automatically corrupted.

Please, help me, which stupid tool is doing such think? how to disable it forever?

Comment: This is one of problems we've occasionally faced with Pootle at phpMyAdmin. In the end we wrote own tool for translating, what turned out to be easier than fixing all issues we had with Pootle. You can find it at http://weblate.org/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try irc://irc.freenode.net/#pootle on freenode to speak directly to users and devs.

Sounds like your using Pootle to translate .properties files directly.  The translator comments seem to be related to code that does fuzzy matching on migration of older translations to new translations.  So the 75% means a 75% match between the two sources and then reusing the translated text.  But since .properties have no concept of fuzzy state my guess is you get those as translated (please check that that is so and that they aren't in fact shown as fuzzy in the UI).

I prefer to do all our .properties work using PO files on Pootle.  So I use prop2po from the Translate Toolkit and then publish the PO files on Pootle. I find that that gives me better control over the state of translations (PO has a concept of translated and fuzzy, while .properties have none of those concepts).